# Использование переменных в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Начинаю писать в JavaScript (API 2gis). Не могу даже использовать переменную.

```
   <head>
    <script>
    var iWidth=1270;
    var map; .....
    </script>
   </head>
```

Затем пытаюсь использовать ее в `<body>`:

```
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: "+iWidth.ToString()+"px; height: 700px">
</div>
```

Comment: Сначала тоже начали работать с ними, а потом оказалось, что не выгодна в любом раскладе, к тому-же, у них не все регионы и  стало платное api поиска, что вообще отпадает желание с ними работать. Взяли гугл (есть все).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript-овые переменные нельзя использовать в произвольном месте html-а.

```
<head>
  <script>
    var iWidth=1270;
    var map; .....
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="height: 700px">
  </div>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("map").style.width = iWidth + "px";
  </script>
</body>
```